# When is the Wpf Dispatcher created?

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

I'm running Wpf application a little bit different than regular way.

I have a class library project that contains Wpf window and I run it just fine.

Sometimes the dispatcher from the window is null by the time I move to the next isntruction after instantiating that window for a reason I can't figure out yet.

I am trying to figure out at which point in a wpf application lifecycle the Dispatcher is supposed to be created?

thanks

```
namespace WpfLib1
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private Window1 _window1;

        public void Launch()
        {
            using (EventWaitHandle eventWaiter = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset,"someName"))
            {
                Thread splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowCustom)) { IsBackground = true };
                splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                splashThread.Start();

                eventWaiter.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        private void ShowCustom()
        {
            _window1 = new Window1();

            EventWaitHandle eventWaiter = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("someName");
            eventWaiter.Set();

            _window1.Closed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                _window1.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
            };

            _window1.Show();
            Dispatcher.Run();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think that most would be more appreciative to see code as well. This might help with future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks for the heads up, I added the existing code in question

Answer (score 0):

You should create a synchronization context which uses the `Dispatcher`:

```
private void ShowCustom()
{
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
        new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

    _window1 = new Window1();

    EventWaitHandle eventWaiter = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("someName");
    eventWaiter.Set();

    _window1.Closed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        _window1.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
    };

    _window1.Show();
    Dispatcher.Run();
}
```